# GMap 3 - driving directions in popup window

Tags: jquery, jquery-gmap3

I'm using the context-menu for GMap3 plugin to show the driving directions.  The directions are displaying correctly.

However, I would like the results of the driving directions to appear in a **popup** window, instead of on the same page.

My guess would be to tweak the call to setDirections:

```
 $map.gmap3({ action: 'setDirections', directions:results});
```

...in a way that would support finding the div with the id of "directions" on the popup window.  Thanks in advance.

Steve

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  Hide the result DIV with css display:none when the map is initialized.  Change `display:none` to `display:block` when points are selected.

```
$('#directionspanel').css('display','block')
```